# How to execute custom query in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Custom query execution in cakephp. I have applied below code.

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$rs = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM customers');
```

It gives me blank array though `customers` table has 20 records.

Please suggest me some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not recommended but somtimes there is no other way! :

1. You should mention namespace of connection manger

   ```
   use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
   ```
2. Get/initialize a connection

   ```
   $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
   ```
3. Execute SQL with something like this

   ```
   $stmt = $conn->execute('SELECT * FROM customers');
   ```
4. Fetch the results

   ```
   $results = $stmt ->fetchAll('assoc');
   ```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Running Select Statements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\SatementInterface::fetch()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_fetch)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\SatementInterface::fetchAll()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_fetchAll)**

Comment: It works... Thank you so much for your approach... Appreciate your work.

Comment: You do know that there are FAR easier ways to get this data, right? I'm assuming that this is just a simplified example. If what you actually want is really the list of all customers, then you should not be using custom queries like this.

Comment: dude at first I mention it "It's not recommended" but it just a example for complex queries cant implement