# Execute custom request on CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to execute a custom SQL query on CakePHP and retrieve results on an array, I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553805/how-to-execute-custom-query-in-cakephp-3-x) but all I get is "true".

I tried something else in my controller. I'm doing this :

```
$req= 'SELECT * FROM recipes r INNER JOIN recipes r1 ON r.i_code = r1.p_code AND r.p_code = "' . $codeProduct . '"';
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$result = $conn->execute($req);
```

Value of `$result` is like the request don't have execute, I see datas like :

```
[protected] _logger => ...
```

And if I do `$result->execute()`, I got true.

What am I doing wrong ? On version 2 it was so simple to do a custom query.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements

Comment: @ndm I was searching that for hours ... Thanks !